# How to set ng-invalid for Kendo Autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui

i have following Kendo autocomplete input with required param:

```
<input type="text"  ng-model="projectDetail.partner.name" ng-init="initAutoCompleteForPartnersCreate()" class="form-control" id="autocompletePartners" required/>
```

Problem is that if input is empty is not applicated rule ng-invalid: which is defined in css.

```
input.ng-invalid {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Could anyone tell me, how can i solve it please?

Many thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved using:

```
input.ng-invalid {
  border: 1px solid red !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
input.ng-pristine, input.ng-invalid {
  border: 1px solid red !important;
}
```